# How to run a Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

On one of my nodes I have three cookbooks in my run list. When the Chef client runs I can see the two of the recipes are executed, but the third is not. What are the possible causes to this?

When I execute the chef client I see:

```
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["vim", "vim::vimrc", "ssh-keys"]
```

Then:

```
Converging 2 resources
Recipe: vim::default
* package[vim] action install (up to date)
Recipe: vim::vimrc  
* template[/etc/vim/vimrc.local] action create (up to date)
```

But the `ssh-keys` recipe is not executed.

What are the possible causes to this? I'm trying to use the [ssh-keys](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/ssh-keys) recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [ssh-keys](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/ssh-keys) cookbook, it requires both operation system user name and the ID of your data bag "users". which means you must have:

- a data bag named users
- entry in that data bag contains the `ssh_keys` key.

Or it will resolve no resources at all if no `ssh_keys` found.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that in my data bag entries I incorrectly called the keys *ssh-key* rather than *ssh_keys*.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the `ssh-keys::default` recipe you will notice that there is an `if` infront:

```
if node[:ssh_keys]
```

At the same time attributes file does not provide this attribute, so it's `nil` and execution does not get inside the block.

Comment: I provide that attribute in the `default_attributes` of the role that also specifies the recipe in its run list for this node. Shouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: Also, even with the `if` statement, wouldn't I see the recipe in the output of the chef client, like the two vim recipes that I showed in the question?

Comment: it shows `Converging 2 resources`, not 2 recipes. you saw only 2 recipes there because there's no further resource needs to be updated.

Comment: @shawnzhu Does this mean that if no resources are updated I won't see any output for that recipe, even if I put logging statements before the `if`?

Comment: @NieldeWet a recipe doesn't matter after the compile phase. so you won't see any resource update in converged resource run queue. the logging statements inside recipes should be executed during compiling phase (I didn't try that). Here's a good blog post titled [The Chef Resource Run Queue](http://erik.hollensbe.org/2013/03/16/the-chef-resource-run-queue/) for your reference.